# Create Watchdog in a batch file and run it on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, watchdog

I've written this code to restart an application when it crashes:

```
@ECHO OFF
:B
SET MyProcess=AL.Distributore.exe
TASKLIST | FINDSTR /I "%MyProcess%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO :StartScripts) ELSE (timeout 120 /nobreak >nul)
GOTO :B 

:StartScripts 
::: //-- Put in the full path to the batch scripts to call
::: //-- Be sure the security context this process runs as has access to execute the below-called batch scripts
if exist D:\Acqualogica\Applicazione\AL.Distributore.exe (START D:\Acqualogica\Applicazione\AL.Distributore.exe)
GOTO :B
```

It works fine if I start with a double click, but I need to run this on the background when the PC starts. I've tried to put the shortcut to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, create a key in the register for autostart, but nothing starts (or works).

OS: Windows 7

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the task scheduler. This feature can be configured using the Windows settings, or by commandline (using `schtasks.exe` (`/SC OnStart`)), but for a start, I'd advise you the Windows settings tool (in the "Trigger" section, you'll see an "OnStart" possibility).